# How do you store a decimal number with a fraction?

Tags: assembly, 68000

if I want to store 10.125 how is it done?

I have this:

```
        ORG     $1000
  DN    DC.L    10.125
        END     $400
```

and in the debug it is stored as:

00001000= 0000000A

That doesnt seem to be getting the fraction part in there.  This is assembly 68k.

Answer (score 1):

A 68k doesn't have a floating point unit, does it?  You can store the value as [fixed-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).  In binary, your number would be `1010.001`, so you need to reserve at least three bits for the fractional part, and you'll be good.  You can then use `0x51` (`1010001b`) to represent `10.125d` in your program.